# Combining both OR and AND in clause query SQL server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, where-clause

I want to select data from a table with clause involving AND and OR.

Here is my sql query:

```
select * 
from WORKTR 
where status='Active' OR status='Inactive'and Start_date='2020-02-10'
```

However, the query above only return 3 from 10 rows in the table which means it does not return the all of the rows that obey the conditions. Please help me to show the right way to write the query.

Comment: You should tell us what you are trying to do - your non working code is ambiguous in intent.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, the correct query depends on your desired result. Please add sample data and the desired result to make clear what your condition is.

Comment: @tiqa You should give us your sample data with the corresponding result. Then we can help you. Maybe the compared value `Start_date='2020-02-10'` is incorrect. So you just get some records that `status='Active'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your condition correctly like below

```
where status='Active' OR (status='Inactive' and Start_date='2020-02-10')
```

Comment: Adding parentheses in might help readability, but this example does the same thing as the code without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis, according to your needs

```
select * 
from WORKTR 
where (status='Active' OR status='Inactive)'and Start_date='2020-02-10'
```

OR

```
select * 
from WORKTR 
where status='Active' OR (status='Inactive'and Start_date='2020-02-10')
```

OR

```
  select * 
    from WORKTR 
    where status IN ('Active','Inactive') and Start_date='2020-02-10'
```

Comment: I already did this but it results to no row were selected